# ListView and propagating click events from children views in the items

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView with custom items - 3 ImageViews and a TextView. I have a call to `setItemsCanFocus(true)`, so I can make the ImageViews clickable. I'm currently using SimpleAdapter to populate the View.

I'd like to trigger the AdapterView's `onItemClick` event when one of those subviews is clicked. The `onItemClickListener` receives a view as the second argument and that can be used to identify which subview was clicked. Frankly, I was expecting this to be the default behaviour but it isn't, unfortunately.

Is there any way to implement this behaviour without bluntly breaking encapsulation (i.e. creating an Adapter that holds a reference to its View)?

What is the accepted way of dealing with events from views in list items? How do you keep the Adapter from knowing too much about the ListView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you have to choose between using onItemClick() or onClick() on individual children. One way to do it however is to make the top-level view of each item clickable.

Comment: Right. So, I just broke encapsulation by registering an `OnClickListener` with the Adapter and passing it on to each of the child views. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: i am getting same problem , but setonitemclicklistener showing nullpointer exception for me and no reaction for onListItemclick() . i want to button as child view click, and each button click perform different activity.

Comment: @Delyan,@RomainGuy - to help me understand the solution, you need to create an OnClickListener in newView() of the adapter class? That means, if there are 10 list items visible on the screen, newView() would be called 10 times and 10 OnClickListeners would be registered, one for each visible item. I have tried this and it works..but is it what you actually meant?

Answer (score 3):

Setting `android:addStatesFromChildren="true"` on the listview in your xml will send clicks on the child elements to the `onItemClick` method in the `onItemClickListener` connected to your listview.

Comment: My Listview gets in a never ending loop if I tick this.