# In ListView when list item has button onListItemClick doesn't work

Tags: android

In my ListView my list item has view as below

this is my row.xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/Peru"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/et_back_yellow"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib_edit"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ib_selector"
            android:contentDescription="@string/edit"
            android:src="@drawable/edit" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="100"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_time"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="100"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib_delete"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ib_selector"
            android:contentDescription="@string/edit"
            android:src="@drawable/delete" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_note"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/title"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" 
        android:background="@color/yellow">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When i click on list item the onListItemClick method doesn't work.But when i delete the buttons form row.xml it works.Can anyone help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your button click code.

Comment: Please post Java Code for your Activity

Answer (score 8):

Use this attribute in your `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout`:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Comment: Thank you very much My Brother it worked but why we used that only for linear and relative layouts?

Comment: It will block your `Button` from taking focus so instead whole `ListView` item will take focus. If it worked then please accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have both `onItemClick` and `onClick` on a child view for a `ListView` as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959840/listview-and-propagating-click-events-from-children-views-in-the-items). The `Button` is focus and click enabled, which will cause the `onItemClick` not to fire.

Comment: Wrong. You can implement `onClick` for certain child `View`s while still using `onItemClick` on whole `ListView` item.

Comment: Romain Guy's answer is correct in question's context. Also read the Delyan's comment on his answer, he was able to do it. I have done it several times.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the prblem I think is the layout weight given to the imageButtons. So try giving weights to all the views in the linear layout along with the weightSum attribute to the linearLayout itself.

The reason the clickListener is not working I feel is the ImageButton is wraping itself throughout the width of the row and the item is no longer has a space that the listener code can execute.