# How to add listener for image in each item from the listView for Android

Tags: android, listview, listener

I meet this problem. I want to create a listView to show all user's information includes nickname, real name and profile image. Now I want to add listener for every profile images, hence user can click each image to view more information. I am not sure how to add the listener. here is the code. Please help me how to add the listener. any help will be appreciated.

```
public class SearchActivity extends ListActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, OnClickListener{

    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;  
    private ListView listView;
    private TextView searchText;
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search); 
        addClickAction((View)this.getListView());   
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                R.layout.search_list_item, 
                null,  // cursor will be added from function onLoadFinished 
                new String[]{DataProvider.COL_NAME, DataProvider.COL_ID,DataProvider.PROFILE_COL_IMAGE},  
                new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.text2,R.id.image},
                0);

        listView = getListView();  
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);  

    }     
    private void searchAction() {
        // fetch user input 
        searchText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.searchText);
        String userName = searchText.getText().toString(); 
        searchText.clearFocus();
        adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() { 
            @Override
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
                switch(view.getId()) { 
                case R.id.text2: 
                    ((TextView)view).setText(String.format("Show user's real name")); 
                    return true;     
                case R.id.image:
                    // show user's profile image
                    byte[] imageByte = cursor.getBlob(columnIndex);
                    ((ImageView)view).setImageBitmap(DbBitmapUtility.getResizedBitmap(DbBitmapUtility.getImage(imageByte),125,125));
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }); 
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.requestFocus(); 
    } 
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //implement abstract functions for LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> 
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(this, 
                DataProvider.CONTENT_URI_PROFILE, 
                new String[]{DataProvider.COL_ID, DataProvider.COL_NAME,DataProvider.PROFILE_COL_IMAGE}, 
                null, 
                null,//new String[]{DataProvider.PROFILE_COL_LASTMSGAT},  
                DataProvider.PROFILE_COL_LASTMSGAT + " DESC"); 
        return loader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        adapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        adapter.swapCursor(null);
    } 
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {  
        case R.id.searchButton: 
            searchAction();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Search button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            break; 
        }     
    } 
    public void addClickAction(View view) {
        ImageButton searchbutton = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
        searchbutton.setOnClickListener(this); 

    }    
}
```

Comment: I think your question or very similar 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16674000/on-a-listview-items-child-click 
2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959840/listview-and-propagating-click-events-from-children-views-in-the-items

Comment: thank you for sharing the link. but im not sure how to create the new adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out something. I can edit setViewBinder. code below

```
adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {

        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
            final int id = columnIndex;
            switch(view.getId()) {
            // here can add one more line in the main page for each account
            case R.id.text2: 
                ((TextView)view).setText(String.format("Show user's real name")); 
                return true;      
            case R.id.avatar:
                byte[] imageByte = cursor.getBlob(columnIndex);
                ((ImageView)view).setImageBitmap(DbBitmapUtility.getResizedBitmap(DbBitmapUtility.getImage(imageByte),125,125));
                ((ImageView)view).setClickable(true); 
                ((ImageView)view).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Go to view more information."+"columnIndex: "+id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                return true; 
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```